# Latex Table Text Wrapping w/ multi-column - way to maintain spacing?

Tags: latex

I am trying to fix the column length but then use multicolumn command in the table. When I use multicolumn it looks like it overrides the column spacing.

I have tried using looking at these answers [Wrong column spacing due to multicolumn in latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25688560/wrong-column-spacing-due-to-multicolumn-in-latex) but this is a more specific then I am looking for. Looking for a more general answer. Some packages can do this (i.e. tabularx) but looking for a 'base' way of doing this.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Test} \\
Test & Test & Test \\
\hline 
     5555 & 5555 & 5555\\
     5555 & 5555 & 5555 \\
     \multicolumn{2}{c}{5555} & 5555 \\
     \hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to make column 1 and 2 be 1cm in width and column 3 be cm while using multicolumn in the table. Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\parbox{width}{text}` to limit the multicolumn cell's width.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{3cm}|}
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\parbox{2cm}{Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Test} \\
    Test & Test & Test \\
    \hline 
    5555 & 5555 & 5555\\
    5555 & 5555 & 5555 \\
    \multicolumn{2}{|c}{5555} & 5555 \\
    \hline 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```